# Generate camera parameters in HalconDotNet

Tags: halcon

In Halcon one can:
`gen_cam_par_area_scan_polynomial (0.008, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.2e-006, 5.2e-006, 640, 512, 1280, 1024, CameraParam)` to get the required camera parameters.

In HalconDotNet (C#) this function does not exist, how can one generate camera parameters in HalconDotNet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look inside function `gen_cam_par_area_scan_polynomial (0.008, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.2e-006, 5.2e-006, 640, 512, 1280, 1024, CameraParam)` in HDevelop you can see that it creates tuple with input parameters that you provide and returns it

```
CameraParam := ['area_scan_polynomial',Focus,K1,K2,K3,P1,P2,Sx,Sy,Cx,Cy,ImageWidth,ImageHeight]
return ()
```

so in C# you can do

```
HTuple cameraParam = new HTuple("area_scan_polynomial", 0.008, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.2e-006, 5.2e-006, 640, 512, 1280, 1024);
```